# php5-mysqlnd not installed on ubuntu

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqlnd

I have already install "mysql".
Now, i want to installed or enabled "mysqlnd".

for that i used

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

But following out put appears on terminal.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-mysqlnd is not available, but is referred to by another    package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
 is only available from another source
 However the following packages replace it:
 php5-mysql

N: Ignoring 'build' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it is not a regular file
N: Ignoring 'build' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it is not a regular file
E: Package 'php5-mysqlnd' has no installation candidate
```

anybody have idea, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: ubuntu version please and `php -v` result

Comment: ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: i think i have to remove mysql then install mysqlnd

Comment: @TamilSelvanC php -v = PHP 5.5.37-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1